# Prestashop - Featured Product - Broken

Tags: css, module, prestashop, product

Hope you are well.

From one day to another my module 'featured product' brokes.
The arrows to slide left - right are many px down so next to another element of the site and the margin on the right isn't applied anymore as you can see on the pics.

The only thing I changed recently in the code is the image above. I only replaced

```
<img src="{$urls.img_url}/**this-part**">
```

Any idea what to do about this and why this might have happen?

Here is website homepage link : lucetteparis.fr

Here is the code of one of the 2 broken 'featured product' module :

```
{**
 * 2007-2019 PrestaShop and Contributors
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License 3.0 (AFL-3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * https://opensource.org/licenses/AFL-3.0
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@prestashop.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade PrestaShop to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize PrestaShop for your
 * needs please refer to https://www.prestashop.com for more information.
 *
 * @author    PrestaShop SA <contact@prestashop.com>
 * @copyright 2007-2019 PrestaShop SA and Contributors
 * @license   https://opensource.org/licenses/AFL-3.0 Academic Free License 3.0 (AFL-3.0)
 * International Registered Trademark & Property of PrestaShop SA
 *}
<section class="featured-products clearfix">
  <a href="https://lucetteparis.fr/34-must-have"><img src="{$urls.img_url}/bandeau-2.jpg">
  <p class="h2 products-section-title text-uppercase">
    <a href="{$allProductsLink2}">{l s='Must Have' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog'}</a>
  </p>
  <div class="products swiper-container swiper-container2">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      {foreach from=$products2 item="product"}
        <div class="swiper-slide">
        {include file="catalog/_partials/miniatures/product.tpl" product=$product}
        </div>
      {/foreach}
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <p class="swiper-button-2">
    <a href="{$allProductsLink2}">{l s='Découvrir' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog'}</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container2', {
    speed: 400,
    spaceBetween: 100,
    slidesPerView: 4,
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
    breakpoints: {
      // when window width is >= 300px
      300: {
        slidesPerView: 2,
        spaceBetween: 20
      },
      // when window width is >= 768px
      768: {
        slidesPerView: 3,
        spaceBetween: 30
      },
      // when window width is >= 1200px
      1200: {
        slidesPerView: 4,
        spaceBetween: 40
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

The page should be stopped right at the end of the image above and the arrows should appear in the middle of the image right below it.

[image: the page should stopped right at the ned of the image above and the arrows should appear in the middle of the image right below it]

Do you have any idea or even some doc that could help me?

Comment: Did this problem always exist our just recently? The CSS causing this issue is located in custom.css meaning this is being added later our by your custom theme. The issue will not happen with a Prestashop default theme, you could try to contact your theme developer.

Comment: Hello Crezzur, thanks for your reply. Yes that's the surprising thing, it was working perfectly well until few days ago and no changes were made to the custom.css file..

Comment: Also, are you sure it's from custom css? I used the dev tool to deactivate all the custom css code but nothing changes. Thank you :)